# Computing PageRank on a digraph with edge weights using GraphFrames

Tags: apache-spark, directed-graph, markov-chains, pagerank, graphframes

Assume I use [GraphFrames](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/index.html) to construct a digraph `g` with edge weights from the positive real numbers. I would then like to compute the PageRank with taking the edge weights into account. I don't see how this can be achieved by looking at the [documentation](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/api/python/graphframes.html#graphframes.GraphFrame.pageRank) for `graphframes.GraphFrame.pageRank`. Calling `results = g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.15, maxIter=10)` will compute the PageRank, but *assuming* edge weights of 1 as far as I can tell. Am I correct?

Compare this to `networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank` which allows for computing PageRank on a digraph with edge weights, see [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_analysis.pagerank_alg.pagerank.html).

Thanks for reading and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that probably we can 'flatten' the data first.

```
val df = Seq((1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,1)).toDF("src", "dst", "weight")
val getArray = udf[Seq[Int], Int] {x => (1 to x).toList.toSeq}
val flatDf = df \
             .withColumn("dummy1", getArray(col("weight"))) \
             .withColumn("dummy2", explode(col("dummy1"))).select("src", "dst")
```